# Como obter o resultado de duas tabelas em sqlite

Tags: sqlite

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu quero obter é as **Currencies** que pertencem a um determinado pais ´
**nome.Pais, code.Currencies, name.Currencies, symbol.Currencies**

```
SELECT * FROM moedapais where alpha2Codes = 'AL';
SELECT * FROM Currencies where code =code.moedapais;
```

***Sendo 'AL' um valor de uma variavel**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa é de um INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT Currencies.code, Currencies.name, Currencies.symbol 
FROM moedapais  
INNER JOIN Currencies ON (Currencies.code = moedapais.code)
INNER JOIN Pais ON (Pais.alpha2Code = moedapais.alpha2Codes)
WHERE alpha2Codes = 'AL';
```